# Possibility to have two versions of same printer driver on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, printing, drivers, print-server

I have print server running Windows Server 2008 R2 with cca 100 of print queues installed.
For easier handling of printer driver updates, mainly universal drivers from printer vendors are being used.

Toshiba has revealed a bug in their driver based on reported incident by our customer and suggested to try updated driver. From the past experience with Toshiba printers, where new updated driver bring some print queues new issues, we're bit worried to update all the print queues with updated driver just to test issue reported on single printer.If I would install this updated driver, it will update current driver that is in use by tens of printers.

I would like to achieve new driver to be installed without updating currently installed version and test the new driver with the specific printer only, rather than updating all print queues with the updated driver.

I was looking for printer driver isolation feature, but doesn't seems to help with my point. I don't have any test server in place unfortunately, where I can do the testing prior to putting driver on production server

To sum up: Wondering if there is a way to have installed two versions of same printer driver at the same time.

Any help and or guidance would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried installing an additional printer using a newer version driver but looking at the installed drivers it is nowhere to be found so I am assuming it just picked up the old driver for this new printer even though I manually pointed it to install the new one.

At this point to test a new version I am going to have to install the driver on a workstation then update the print server if it works out.

I hope this this information helps someone in a similar situation as I don't think multiple versions of the same driver are possible since the file is the same name when it gets copied to the system directory.  It is under my impression it will not overwrite the existing file.

Comment: Hi, i. E. It is possible to have the same driver in Differenz version avaie, i. E. HP pcl4, 5,6 etc

Comment: I believe as long as the driver file is a different name you should be okay but I didn't test this.  I know PS and PCL can co-exist but obviously the file names differ.